# Laravel HTML form issue

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

```html
 <form action="/group/{id}/save/group" method="POST">
    @csrf                              
       <table id="modal-table">                                      
         @foreach($user_list->get() as $f)
           <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class="image">
                    @if($f->follower->avatar_location)  
                        <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$f->follower->avatar_location)}}" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;" />
                    @else
                        <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/user.png" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;"/>
                    @endif
                 </div>
                 <div class="detail">                       
                 @if($f->follower->verified == 1)
                    {{ $f->follower->name }}<img id="verified_img_sm_mess_list" src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/octagonal_star.png" alt="Recensioni">
                 @else
                    {{ $f->follower->name }}</h3>
                 @endif  
                    <small id="mess_list_uname">{{ '@'.$f->follower->username }}</small>
                 </div>
                 <input name="group" value="{{ $group->hobby->id }}">
                 <input name="person" value="{{ $f->follower->id }}">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn-link">Go</button>
             </td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
    </table>
  </form>
```

Hey a small problem! in the Foreach loop and every member in the list, I tried some bare-bones to get each users id and hobby id (to add to database, but that's not important). For some reason, when I take the input 'name' and click the Go button, All "id's" of everyone in the list are executed, Not the individual id of each user. Meaning.. each user displays their individual id and a go button, but click go and all id's are collected, not just one. It's probably really obvious but any ideas why this is happening?? Thanks!

Comment: Your `<form>` wraps everything, so everything is submitted... You probably need to move that `<form>` inside of your `@foreach()` loop to accomplish what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks! Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

Like said Tim Lewis in the comment, you need to put your form inside your foreach, so when the "Go" button is clicked, only the corresponding form will send the data, like this :

```html
<table id="modal-table">                                      
  @foreach($user_list->get() as $f)
    <form action="/group/{id}/save/group" method="POST">
    @csrf   
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="image">
            @if($f->follower->avatar_location)  
            <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$f->follower->avatar_location)}}" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;" />
            @else
            <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/user.png" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;"/>
            @endif
          </div>
          <div class="detail">                       
            @if($f->follower->verified == 1)
            {{ $f->follower->name }}<img id="verified_img_sm_mess_list" src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/octagonal_star.png" alt="Recensioni">
            @else
            {{ $f->follower->name }}</h3>
            @endif  
            <small id="mess_list_uname">{{ '@'.$f->follower->username }}</small>
          </div>
          <input name="group" value="{{ $group->hobby->id }}">
          <input name="person" value="{{ $f->follower->id }}">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-link">Go</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="modal-table">                                      
  @foreach($user_list->get() as $f)
    <form action="/group/{id}/save/group" method="POST">
    @csrf   
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="image">
            @if($f->follower->avatar_location)  
            <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$f->follower->avatar_location)}}" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;" />
            @else
            <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/user.png" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;"/>
            @endif
          </div>
          <div class="detail">                       
            @if($f->follower->verified == 1)
            {{ $f->follower->name }}<img id="verified_img_sm_mess_list" src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/octagonal_star.png" alt="Recensioni">
            @else
            {{ $f->follower->name }}</h3>
            @endif  
            <small id="mess_list_uname">{{ '@'.$f->follower->username }}</small>
          </div>
          <input name="group" value="{{ $group->hobby->id }}">
          <input name="person" value="{{ $f->follower->id }}">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-link">Go</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

check this  part of  Jérôme W post

```
<form action="/group/{id}/save/group" method="POST">
```

Change to this

```
 <form action="/group/{{$group->id}}/save/group" method="POST">
```